# While loop does not show any output

Tags: python, function, while-loop, return, sqrt

Please find time to answer this question.

When I print the following code, my while loop does not show any output.

```
import math
epsilon=.000000001

def mysqrt(a):
    while True:
       x=a/2
       y=(x+a/x)/2
       if abs(y-x)<epsilon:
         return (y)
        



def test_square_root():
    a=1.0
    print ('a'," " , "mysqrt(a)", " ", "math.sqrt(a)", " ", "diff")
    while a<10.0:
       print (a," " , mysqrt(a), math.sqrt(a),abs(mysqrt(a)-math.sqrt(a)))
       a+=1
     
test_square_root()
```

For the time being, I am not concthe erned about formatting of the table. I just need the following output. I am using the square root formula y=(x+a/x)/2

```
a mysqrt(a) math.sqrt(a) diff
1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
2.0 1.41421356237 1.41421356237 2.22044604925e-16
3.0 1.73205080757 1.73205080757 0.0
4.0 2.0 2.0 0.0
5.0 2.2360679775 2.2360679775 0.0
6.0 2.44948974278 2.44948974278 0.0
7.0 2.64575131106 2.64575131106 0.0
8.0 2.82842712475 2.82842712475 4.4408920985e-16
9.0 3.0 3.0 0.0
```

Comment: [Execute it step by step](https://n9.cl/so77264679) and see what it does. You'll notice your `while` loop is infinite because its variables never change.

Comment: What formula are you using?

Comment: The while-loop never changes the value of `x`, so it will perform the same calculation forever. The algorithm works by calculating the difference between the current result and the previous result; if the difference is less than a threshold value (*epsilon*), the loop should terminate - but your code doesn't save the previous result, so that can never happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code slightly and the code is working for me

```
import math

epsilon = 1e-9

def mysqrt(a):
    x = a / 2
    while True:
        y = (x + a / x) / 2
        if abs(y - x) < epsilon:
            return y
        x = y

def test_square_root():
    a = 1.0
    print('a', 'mysqrt(a)', 'math.sqrt(a)', 'diff')
    while a < 10.0:
        result = mysqrt(a)
        print(a, result, math.sqrt(a), abs(result - math.sqrt(a)))
        a += 1

test_square_root()
```

[image: My Console Output]

Answer (score 0):

For sure there is something wrong with mysqrt() function..

```
import math
epsilon=.000000001

def mysqrt(a):
    while True:
       x=a/2
       y=(x+a/x)/2
       if abs(y-x)<epsilon:
         return (y)
       else:
        return("abs(y-x) >= epsilon")
    
def test_square_root():
    a=1.0
    print('a', "mysqrt(a)", "math.sqrt(a)", "diff")
    while a<10.0:
       print(a, mysqrt(a), math.sqrt(a),abs(mysqrt(a)-math.sqrt(a)))
       a+=1.0

# test_square_root()
print(mysqrt(1))
```

Try to fix your mysqrt function

Answer (score 0):

Let's state what's going on:

1. You call a function (a)
2. Your function (a) formats data using another function (b)
3. Function (b) uses a `while True` loop with no limit, this means it'll repeat forever if the return is never called. This is why you're not printing anything

Your code also doesn't seem to be fully efficient, math shouldn't really be "searched" as there's almost always an algebraïc answer.

Please state what exactly you're trying to do and I'll try to explain it in a simpler way.

Comment: Can you guys just tell me one thing? My code is running now. I just added x=y at the end of the mysqrt function, just as  Mahboob Nur did. Why was my code not working before writing x=y? What is the significance of x=y here. Folllowing is my revised code which is working.

Comment: import math
epsilon=.000000001

def mysqrt(a):
    x=a/2
    while True:
        y=(x+a/x)/2
        if abs(y-x)<epsilon:
            return (y)
        x=y
        



def test_square_root():
    a=1.0
    print ('a'," " , "mysqrt(a)", " ", "math.sqrt(a)", " ", "diff")
    while a<10.0:
        print (a," " , mysqrt(a), math.sqrt(a),abs(mysqrt(a)-math.sqrt(a)))
        a+=1
     
test_square_root()